# JS Files declared on Layout page of my MVC project not loading on partial Views

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

On my project I declare all JS files I will need on the _layout.cshtml but my partialviews are not loading these files.
I need to declare them on every partialview which is causing my troubles.

Here is my layout bottom part.
One of the problems is when I append my "menu" to the _layout.
I need the "scripts.bundle.js" on every page so I call from the layout but it is not working on partialviews...

what am I doing wrong?

```
    <script>var hostUrl = "@Url.Content("~/Content/")";</script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/assets/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/assets/js/scripts.bundle.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/assets/plugins/custom/datatables/datatables.bundle.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/assets/js/custom/apps/ecommerce/reports/views/views.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/assets/js/widgets.bundle.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/assets/js/custom/widgets.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/assets/plugins/custom/fslightbox/fslightbox.bundle.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/src/js/components/menu.js")"></script>

</body>
<!--end::Body-->
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        $('#menuPrincipal').load('@Url.Content("~/Home/V_Menu")'), function () { $('#menuPrincipal').append(); }
        return false;

    });

</script>
```

I need all pages from the project reading the js files from the layout page but it is not working....